# FB.login doesn't return authResponse from inner page

Tags: authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

On FB.login I got

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token \ in JSON at position

for

> {\"algorithm\":\"HMAC-SHA256\",\"code\":\"...

But I'm waiting for **authResponse** and **status** from this code:

```
$(function () {
  window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: server_data.keys.fb_app_id,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.6'
    });
  };

  (function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  $(document).on('click', '[login]', function() {
    $('[login] .auth__auth-btn_text').text('Loading ...');
    FB.login(function (response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    }, {scope: 'public_profile,user_friends,email'});
  });

  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }

});
'use strict';
```

**UPDATE**

function response is ok - **authResponse** from http://localhost:5000/

But I got **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token** still on calling from inner page like **http://localhost:5000/note?id=1**

Even after changing developers.facebook.com/apps settings:

[image]

Comment: what is in your statusChangeCallback function? what is the result of console.log(response) in the FB.login callback?

Comment: @luschn, this method is not calling at all. Because of exception on FB.login

Comment: can you add a test link?

Comment: @luschn, I updated my question

Comment: well...we can´t do anything with a localhost testlink...lol